# Цикл for перебор списка, что не так?

Tags: python-3.x

Тренируюсь работать с циклом for: 
Не перебирает список, выполняет первую итерацию ('Yes'), независимо от того есть имя в списке или нет. Помогите пожалуйста, в инете ответ не обрел.

```
name = input("Введите имя для проверки: ")
names = ["Kate", "Elena", "Sergej", "Oleg", "Vasya"]
for name in names:
    if name in names:
        print('Yes')
    else:
        print('No')
```

Comment: Переменная цикла переписывает объявленную выше переменную “name”

Comment: А как правильно?

Comment: Правильно без цикла =) но если очень хотите именно цикл - смотрите ответ

Comment: input("Введите имя для проверки: ") in names

Answer (score 1):

Вот рабочий код:

```
name = input("Введите имя для проверки: ")
names = ["Kate", "Elena", "Sergej", "Oleg", "Vasya"]
if name in names:
  print ("yes")
else:
  print ("no")
```

Проблема в том, что `in` и так пробегает по массиву сам, чтобы проверить вхождение. А ты делал как:

1. Назначил переменную `name` как имя
2. Цикл сделал по той же переменной,
   то есть `name` у тебя уже являлась каждым элементом массив
3. И потом
   проверял, а является ли `name` в массиве.

То есть ты перезаписал и смотрел далеко не то.

Comment: Спасибо) Так я умею, тут в ролике смотрел о цикле for решил извратиться, в любом случае спасибо.

Comment: `IN` и так пробегает сам по массиву. Если задача стоит проверить наличие, то мой вариант быстрее.

Comment: Согласен, простое лучше сложного, если я верно цитирую основателя

Comment: @mepihindeveloper не заметил ваш ответ когда свой правил +) вернул всё в спять =)

Comment: @ОлегБуткевич `names = ["Kate", "Elena", "Sergej", "Oleg", "Vasya"]
result = input("Введите имя для проверки: ") in names`

Comment: @mepihindeveloper, лучше в ответ вставьте как альтернативный вариант =)

Answer (score 0):

Если очень хочется цикл:

```
namein = input("Введите имя для проверки: ")
names = ["Kate", "Elena", "Sergej", "Oleg", "Vasya"]
for name in names:
    if namein == name:
        print('Yes')
    else:
        print('No')
```

Comment: Спасибо, не совсем понял в чем фишка, буду искать

Comment: Посмотрите на то как записано условие и на отличие в наименованиях `namein` и `name`

Comment: Это я понял, а почему namein? Это оператор in? Занимаюсь меньше месяца, во многом плаваю по что

Comment: нет, просто сокращение от `NameInput` можете обозвать ее как угодно, главное чтобы не совпадали имена переменных. `for name in names:` вот в этом операторе каждый раз в переменную `name` записывается очередной элемент из `names`.

Comment: Спасибо) Да без цикла логичнее, учу далее))